# Onchange event not firing to any JS function

Tags: javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu, dom-events, onchange

I am trying to have an option from a dropdown menu be sent to a Javascript function so I can query a database using AJAX by calling a PHP function.  Unfortunately, it seems as if my `onchange` event is not even firing at all.  I attempted to redirect the `onchange` event to a simple Javascript function just to test, and that is not working either.  I can't for the life of me seem to figure it out.  Attached below is my sample code (HTML and the sample test Javascript function):

HTML:

```
    <div id="Category_and_Food">
            <form>
                <select id="categories" onchange="tested()">
                    <option value = "">Please select a category</option>
                    <option value="Appetizers">Appetizers</option>
                    <option value="Entree">Entree</option>
                    <option value="Specials">Specials</option>
                    <option value="Drink">Drinks</option> 
                    <option value="Meat">Meat</option>
                    <option value="Soup">Soup</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        <br />
        <div id="cat_display"><b>Please select a category above</b></div>   
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function tested()
{
var x = document.getElementById("categories").value;
document.getElementById("cat_display").innerHTML = x;
{
</script>
```

Prior, I also tested this function with the `onchange` event being `onchange="tested(this.value)"` with the function reflecting the changed input.

Answer (score 1):

You have a backwards `}`:

```
function tested()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("categories").value;
    document.getElementById("cat_display").innerHTML = x;
} // <----
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/L2abu/1/

Be sure to run your code through a tool like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) to check for syntax errors.